# Why doesn't my function allow this input?

Tags: php, function

```
$name = func_get_arg(func_get_args);
```

I tried to get the last passed argument of my PHP function.

But instead of giving me the last argument I get this two errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant func_get_args - assumed 'func_get_args'

Warning: func_get_arg() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given
```

Can someone explain me why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: PHP documentation is great [`func_get_arg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php)

Comment: The code doesn't make any sense...?! What's `func_get_args` supposed to be?

Comment: As far as I understand func_get_args gives back the number of passed arguments. So a possible result would be like 4. Oh - I think I found my trouble. While the testing I mixed up the function itself.

Comment: You understood wrong. Please read the manual again.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to get the last returned value from the func_get_arg function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function name as an argument to `func_get_arg()`. This will never work in PHP.

Use this:

```
$arg = func_get_arg(func_num_args() -1);
```

or, as an alternative:

```
$arg = array_pop(func_get_args());
```

Comment: After I saw my mistake in my own code (I tested that much so I didn't see that I tried to use `func_get_args` instead of `func_num_args`. I'm curious, why do I need to decrease the nummber by one?

Comment: because array indexes in PHP starting by `0`. Meaning: `array('foo')` will have a count of `1` but you need to access the element `0`.. That's why `-1`

Answer (score 1):

You can get last argument using

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();

    $arg_list = func_get_args();

    echo "Last argument: " . $arg_list[$numargs-1];
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will return last argument passed to the function
$lastArgument = func_get_arg(func_num_args()-1);
```